# Netlogo: How to format number on output

Tags: netlogo

I would like to format a number in NetLogo in a way that trailing zeros after the decimal point are not supressed, i.e. have the output 0.200 for the following command instead of 0.2:

```
observer> print 0.200  
0.2
```

Is there a way to achieve this in NetLogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not in netlogo setup to my knowledge. Here is a dandy procedure that does the trick

```
to-report pad-zeros [in sig]
   let out (word in) 
   if not member? "." in [set out word out "."]
   while [ length out - position "." out < sig][set out (word out "0")]
   report out
end
```

The drawback is that it reports a string. This is minimally annoying because you are only using it for output.